# Is there a way to cache a View so that queries against it are quick?

Tags: mysql, view

I'm extremely new to Views so please forgive me if this is a silly question, but I have a View that is really helpful in optimizing a pretty unwieldy query, and allows me to select against a small subset of columns in the View, however, I was hoping that the View would actually be stored somewhere so that selecting against it wouldn't take very long.

I may be mistaken, but I get the sense (from the speed with which `create view` executes and from the duration of my queries against my View) that the View is actually run as a query prior to the external query, every time I select against it.

I'm really hoping that I'm overlooking some mechanism whereby when I run CREATE VIEW it can do the hard work of querying the View query *then, so that my subsequent select against this static View would be really swift.

BTW, I totally understand that obviously this VIEW would be a snapshot of the data that existed at the time the VIEW was created and wouldn't reflect any new info that was inserted/updated subsequent to the VIEW's creation.  That's actually EXACTLY what I need.

TIA

Comment: So what you want is a materialized view, not the view mysql provides which is just an alias for a huge query. As of mysql 5.1, SELECT queries against the view are cached, therefore any subsequent queries should be quick. How exactly is something not working for you here? Do you use subqueries in queries creating the view?

Comment: I'm using a huge query with many subselects in my VIEW, and it doesn't appear to be caching at all. As a proof of concept I simply called `select count(id) from myView` which I presume should be pretty snappy if the result of myView was cached, but alas it takes just as long as any other query against it.  Is the problem that my View has subselects? (I'm not sure if that's what you mean by subqueries or if there's a distinction).

Comment: Subselect or subquery - so we're talking about the same thing. MySQL uses its own query cache. Say, we have a table with 1 mil rows, you query it like `select count(*)` - 1st time will be slow-ish, 2nd time will be instantaneous because it'll pull cached data. Same rule applies to views, with the difference that MySQL doesn't cache subselect results. All this means is that the result you get from your view *will not be cached internally* by MySQL if you have subselects. Therefore, it'll always run the queries from the scratch, if you will. And that's why your view will be slow.

Comment: What you can do is, of course, optimize the tables involved in the query which you used to create the view. A view is just basically an alias so you don't have to type tens of JOINs etc., which means the view you want is not something that's materialized. You have an option to literally create a table out of your view and copy the data in that table (materialize the view), or you can optimize MySQLs engine settings and the original query. Seeing there's not sufficient info, there's nothing more that can be done without seeing the query and indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately the view is a pivot table, so there's not a lot I can do to avoid subselects (since it's several dozen subselects from the same table, against specific user_ids). Sounds like Materialization is my only option. I'll deal with the 2 minute selects, for the moment, and see if that gets any worse over time. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: Sounds like you have some nasty EAV going on in there. Sadly, the materialization is your only way to achieve any kind of performance querying such a dataset. Good luck and godspeed :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you want to do is materialize your view. Have a look at http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views.

Comment: hmm... well based on that tutorial it looks like in mySQL Materializing views is a bit of a summersault. I was hoping that it would be as simple as adding some keyword to my view creation.  Oh well... thanks for letting me know what it's called! :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: you could always move to DB2 where such a beast _is_ possible just by adding a single word. You may not consider the cost worth it however :-)

Comment: sadly that's not an option for us at this time :)

Comment: You don't want to go near DB2.

Comment: While you're refreshing the materialised view though anything that wants to use the view will get incomplete results? Surely you need a solution where the view always has a full set of data and the data replacement is atomic

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about are materialised views, a feature of (at least) DB2 but not MySQL as far as I know.

There are ways to *emulate* them by creating/populating a table periodically, or on demand, but a true materialised view knows when the underlying data has changed, and only recalculates if required.

If the data will never change once the view is created (as you seem to indicate in a comment), just create a brand new table to hold the subset of data and query *that.* People always complain about slow speed but rarely about data storage requirements :-)

Comment: ironically, I really don't want the cached *table to ever change. I'm doing stuff like `select * where date between x and y` so, my cached table represents a fixed set of data that won't be shifting at all. I just want to be able to quickly select against that data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with:

- A [MySQL Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)
- A separate table (for caching)
- The [REPLACE INTO ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) statement.

Here's a working example.

```
-- create dummy data for testing
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
 id INT NOT NULL,
 groupvar INT NOT NULL,
 myvar INT
);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,1);

-- create the view, making sure rows have a unique identifier (groupvar)
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT groupvar, SUM(myvar) as myvar_sum
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY groupvar;

-- create cache table, setting primary key to unique identifier (groupvar)
CREATE TABLE MyView_Cache (PRIMARY KEY (groupvar))
SELECT *
FROM MyView;

-- create a table to keep track of when the cache has been updated (optional)
CREATE TABLE MyView_Cache_updated (update_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (update_id));

-- create event to update cache table (e.g., daily)
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT MyView_Cache_Event
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      BEGIN 

      REPLACE INTO MyView_Cache
      SELECT *
      FROM MyView_Cache;
      
      INSERT INTO MyView_Cache_updated
      SELECT NULL, NOW() AS last_updated;

      END |
DELIMITER ;
```

You can now query MyView_Cache for faster response times, and query MyView_Cache_updated to inform users of the last time the cache was updated (in this example, daily).

Answer (score 0):

Since a view is basically a `SELECT` statement you can use [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) to improve performance.

But first you should check if :

- you can add indexes in the tables involved to speed up the query (use `EXPLAIN`)
- the data isn't changing very often you can materialize the view (make snapshots)

Answer (score 0):

Use a materiallised view.. It can store data like count sum etc but yes after updating the table you need to refresh the view to get correct results as they are not auto updated.. Moreover after querying from view the results are stored in cache so the memory cycles reduces to 2 which are 4 in case of querying from the table itself. So it gets efficient from the second time.. When you query for 1st time from view the data is fetched from main memory and is stored in cache after it.