# Is it possible to only update mysql view when there is changes in data?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a query that is really slow (big numbers), it takes 60 seconds to run.

I thought that making the result a VIEW could solve the problem, but I see now that a view is updated for every query to the view.

The thing is that the real data of this view only updates like once every month, so its not needed to be updated on every query.

Is this possible? To make a view only update when there is changes to the original table?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with mysql views as of 5.6.  The easiest thing would to create a reporting table that gets populated once a month instead of a dynamic view.   You could create a time triggered event to run the SQL to populate it: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html

Comment: yes that is a solution. i was just thinking that if a view could just update only on data change, it would be even simpler.

Comment: @KristianRafteseth here's a attempt at it, but it's basically what I described: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687736/is-there-a-way-to-cache-a-view-so-that-queries-against-it-are-quick

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to write a function which contain the insert/update/delete function and update the view. Or you can use mysql trigger and update the view when the table has modification