# MySQL update a master field only if condition is true

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to update SQL in such a way, for example.

Master Table has a column called INVOICESCOUNT.

When an invoice is deleted successfully, then the INVOICESCOUNT is decreased.

For example, a SQL psuedo-code statement like this:

```
Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500;
Update Customers SET INVOICECOUNT=INVOICECOUNT-1 WHERE Customer=1  (if prior statement returns 1 affected row);
```

I need it to be embedded within the same SQL statement instead of having the source code handling executing the 2 statements separately.

Thanks for any advice.  Please also let me know if there is any minimal MySQL version requirement if there is such a solution.

UPDATE with more info:  note that the list of Customers I present to the user can be very different each time, example,  CustomerGroupID=? or CustomerCreated within a certain date, so the Customers query cannot be cached efficiently, as such I prefer to update the INVOICECOUNT (as it will be hit on many times in an hour by different users listing different groups of customers).

Comment: You don't need a table to record your counts. SQL can count it for you

Comment: You shouldn't be storing _derived data_ in tables in an RDBMS, including aggregates like "count of rows in another table meeting some condition" - instead use a `VIEW`. There are _many_ reasons for not storing derived data like that, namely because it _goes stale_ and becomes incorrect. Databases should be designed so that they never contain internally derived data that can do stale.

Answer (score 1):

Better idea: instead have a `VIEW` that shows you Customer's invoice counts:

```
CREATE VIEW CustomersInfo AS

SELECT
    CustomerId,
    COUNT(*) AS InvoiceCount
FROM
    Invoices
GROUP BY
    CustomerId
;
```

Then you'd use it like so:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerId,
    COALESCE( ci.InvoiceCount, 0 ) AS InvoiceCount
FROM
    Customers AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomersInfo AS ci ON c.CustomerId = ci.CustomerId
```

(Don't use an `INNER JOIN`, otherwise Customers *without* any invoices won't be in the output).

Comment: thanks for the alternative way of doing this.  This sample could be useful for some other client-based sql code.  Maybe the example I gave is not the best as our scenario is more complex.  but due to some internal reason for performance reasons, I cannot count the Invoices every time such a "query invoices count" comes along.  Is there a way to execute a conditional SQL statement as in my original question?

Comment: @PeterJones Performance isn't an excuse: [MySQL supports cached _materialized views_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687736/is-there-a-way-to-cache-a-view-so-that-queries-against-it-are-quick). If your original question is not representative of your actual problem then **you should edit your question post to describe what your problem actually is**.

Comment: please see "UPDATE with more info" where I need to list very different groups of Customers each time so caching may not work well.  my apologies for not mentioning this point.  Your View example is a good idea and I can use it in other scenarios.  Thanks for the sample. Much appreciated. I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Invoices(INVOICE INT)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLe Customers(Customer int,INVOICECOUNT int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (1,1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER del_after AFTER DELETE ON Invoices
> FOR EACH ROW
> Update Customers SET INVOICECOUNT=INVOICECOUNT-1 WHERE Customer=1
> ```

> ```
> Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers
> ```
>
> ```
> Customer | INVOICECOUNT
> -------: | -----------:
>        1 |            1
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Invoices VALUES (400)
> ```

> ```
> Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers
> ```
>
> ```
> Customer | INVOICECOUNT
> -------: | -----------:
>        1 |            1
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Invoices VALUES (500)
> ```

> ```
> Delete From Invoices where INVOICE=500;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers
> ```
>
> ```
> Customer | INVOICECOUNT
> -------: | -----------:
>        1 |            0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=806c9848b7b32a753de1adc9c3ef6e7d)*

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you probably don't need to store the invoice count in a table column, however if you MUST have the invoice count column for any reason your best bet might be a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE removeinvoice
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM invoices WHERE invoice=500;
    UPDATE customers SET invoicecount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you just call that stored procedure.

```
CALL removeinvoice;
```